# Using oauth2 by server in behalf of client

Tags: google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to build an application which requires to access user's google apis on their behalf once they give consent.

What I am trying to build?

An azure database is scheduled to put some data on user specified spreadsheets on their google drive.

What is the problem?

I am unable to figure out how to upload data to user specified spreadsheets when the user is offline.

What workflow do I want?

1. User logs in with Google Account
2. User gives consent to web app to access spreadsheets api (just once)
3. Thereafter my server should update the sheets as per the schedule without the user's interferance
4. User can later check back to see the updated data on their sheets.

I want to know how should I implement to get this mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request offline access of the user get a refresh token. Store the refresh token and when ever you need to access the users account later use the refresh token to request a new access token.

I recommend looking for a google client library in your chosen language most of them handle this functionality internally.